# I want to prove the following limit $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1 $ using the definition of limit.

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the following limit
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
\end{equation}
using the definition of limit. Then:
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{\sin x}{x}-1 \right|=\left|\frac{\sin x}{ x}\right| \left|1 -\frac{x}{\sin x} \right|\leq \left|1 -\frac{x}{\sin x} \right|
\end{equation}
Also
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{x}{\sin x}-1 \right|\leq \left|\frac{1}{\cos x}-1 \right|=\left|\frac{\sin^{2} x}{\cos x(1+\cos x)}\right|
\end{equation}
noting that $\cos x>0$ in the neighbourhood $(-\delta_{\epsilon},\delta_{\epsilon})$, I have:
\begin{equation}
\leq \left|\frac{\sin^{2} x}{\cos x}\right|=\left| \sin x \right| \left| \tan x \right|\leq \left| \tan x \right|\leq  \tan \delta_{\epsilon} \leq \epsilon
\end{equation}
it is verified for $\delta_{\epsilon}=arc\tan(\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$  (for example)
Can anyone "see" a simpler solution (using the definition of limit)?

Comment: How about this: If you accept that cosx is the derivative of sinx, then:

The limit as h->0

$\frac{sinh-sin0}{h}=cosh=1$

Comment: that is probably circular and certainly not in spirit of problem (to invoke derivatives)

Comment: Would you accept the "squeeze" principle?  (i.e., if $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \neq p$ in some neighborhood $N(p)$ and the limits of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ as $x \to p$ both $= a$ then the limit of $g(x)$ as $x \to p$ is also $= a$?)  If so, you can use $f(x) = \cos x$ and $h(x) = 1/\cos x$.

Comment: is a good solution, but I wanted to prove the $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ using the definition of limit.

Comment: Understood.  I was just thinking the squeeze principle is pretty close to following directly from the definition, so figured it was worth suggesting that approach.  I don't have a ready improvement to suggest to yours for directly from the definition.

Comment: See this http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X for 3 different proofs of the theorem.

Comment: However, thank you for your opinion.